# What's the use of <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">?

Tags: html, css

It's already asked question but I have still doubt. I made a web page using html, css and java script. When I used `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` it's still same as when I was not used. So, my question is when is the correct time  to use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`.
And please guys don't fire on me. I really need help.

Comment: Did you try it on a mobile web browser?

Comment: Jhon, this is for [mobile, read here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: You can check this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: @Ry- I try it on google chorme toogle device toolbar.

Comment: The correct time to use `content="width=device-width"` is any time you want your page to be responsive. Check out [mydevice.io](https://www.mydevice.io/#compare-devices) (scroll down to 'Compare Devices'). The 'CSS Width' column will tell you how large your website will appear on many popular phones. Without `content="width=device-width"` a phone will display the site at the phone's 'Physical Width' which is almost always much larger, thus making the site appear "zoomed way out".

Comment: In css file for body and for maximum div classes I used `Position:fixed` and for height and width I used 100%. So it is creating any problem to render my site responsive.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a responsive meta tag only if your website is designed to be responsive to different sizes of viewports.

A `<meta> viewport` element gives instructions to the browser on how to control the pages dimension and scaling.

The `content="width=device-width"` sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device or viewport which will vary depending on the device. So it basically means that the browser will (probably) render the width of the page at the width of its own screen. (So if that screen is 320px wide, the browser window will be 320px wide, rather than way zoomed out and showing 960px or whatever that device does by default).

Hope this helps :)

This are great resources: 
https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design
http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/mobile-first-responsive-web-design/

and here is a collection of resources if you'd like to read a bit more about it:

https://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/resources.html

Comment: In css file for body and for maximum div classes I used `Position:fixed` and for height and width I used 100%. So it is creating any problem to render my site responsive.

Comment: Are you designing mobile first and creating media query for other viewports/devices?

Comment: No, first I design for pc/laptop(screen size about  15 inches)  then I am checking for mobile phone browser (iphone 8+).

Comment: When designing a responsive website you always want to design for mobile first and then with media queries you alter the styling for bigger viewports.

Answer (score 0):

Some moving pictures to illustrate the basic meta viewport.

As stated in one comment, there is some differences between CSS pixel and Screen size. Css Pixel Ratio (or Retina / HD screens / whatever marketing will call it) helps you calculate the available width available for your elements.

https://css-tricks.com/probably-use-initial-scale1/

Comment: Initial scale is not the same as initial width.

Comment: You still have an explanation and illustration for width=device-width in the first part of the article.

Comment: Is the explanation is only in the link, you should quote it in the answer itself.